# Calling a generic function from inside a task?

Tags: c#, generics, task

I'm trying to call a generic function from a different thread but for some reason my generic parameter T does not seem to be recognized from within the task. My generic function looks like this

```
   private T extractSingleItem<T>(NpgsqlDataReader dr) where T : new()
    {
        T c = new T();
        if (dr.Read())
        {

            foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
            {
                try
                {
                    //extracting the column name for the property's attributes
                    string column = ((TableAttribute)p.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(TableAttribute))).Column;
                    c.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).SetValue(c, dr[column]);
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }

        return c;
    }
```

and I am trying to call it like this

```
public override void execQuery<T>(string query, Dictionary<string, dynamic> qparams, EventHandler<dynamic> callBack) 
    {


        Task.Run(() => {

            string db = mConnection.Database;
            if (mConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                mConnection.Open();


            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, mConnection);

            command.Parameters.AddRange(qparams.Select(x => new NpgsqlParameter(x.Key, x.Value)).ToArray());

            NpgsqlDataReader dr = null;

            try
            {
                dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch
            {
                command.Connection = genNewConn();
                dr = command.ExecuteReader();

            }

            var res = extractSingleItem<T>(dr);

        });


    }
```

but someone I get this error

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0310  'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method"

only when I call from within the task.

Comment: `var res = extractSingleItem<T>(dr);` that's not right. It should be something like var `res = extractSingleItem<string>(dr);`

Comment: How so? the type T is not always a string, I need it to be different things at run time

Comment: Is the T not provided by the executing method in the angle brackets <T> of it, such that i would call it like

execQuery<SomeType>()?

Comment: @Shady3cho There's some confusion because the `<T>` was not visible before your edit

Answer (score 2):

In `extractSingleItem` you have the generic constaint `where T : new()`. You have not defined the same constraint in `execQuery`, so there's no guarantee that the T satisfies it. Just add the same generic constraint to `execQuery` and it'll work:

```
public override void execQuery<T>(string query, Dictionary<string, dynamic> qparams, EventHandler<dynamic> callBack) 
    where T : new()
```

Comment: Wow thank you, i dont know how I missed that, i need to add "where T : new()" on the overidden function